# Cannot access links under the project directory in localhost (.htaccess) Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, path

Whenever I use a path in hyperlinks, form actions, etc, I can't access the root directory as being **my project**, it always takes me to localhost, so for example, if a try to access something like this through a hyperlink:

**/home/index**

I eventually get redirected to localhost, and the url becomes: **localhost/home/index** instead of **localhost/myproject/home/index**

I tried some other solutions on satckoverflow, but none of them worked out, I'm gonna list them here:

Tried to change ->

```
DocumentRoot /myproject/

DocumentBase /myproject/
```

ps: it only works if I explicitly say : /myproject/home/index, but that's not good.

I just want a solution that applies only for the current project so that I won't need to configure apache specific files every time I want to use an specific project. So I need something that has to be changed only in .htaccess in order to be more flexible!

Here's a screenshot of .htaccess, folder structure, and one of the html files where I utilize hyperlinks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes in `.htaccess` will not gonna help you. `.htaccess` rules may affect URL of the request, but will not modify your response, so if you put `/home/about` as URL in HTML link it will never change it to `/myproject/home/about` and this URL will be always relative to current domain.

However, if you have single entry file, you may use [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag in the header of your layout to set a base path for all relative URLs on this page.

```
<base href="<?= htmlspecialchars(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), ENT_QUOTES) ?>"/>
```

Then link defined like `<a href="home/index">Home</a>` will point to `http://localhost/myproject/home/index`.

Note that this will not affect non-HTML links, `header("Location: /home/index");` will point to `http:/localhost/home/index`. Also `dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])` may not always be reliable. You may consider using some framework with a helper method for getting relative path of app or copy some solutions from it - detecting the base path of the request may be [quite complicated](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/353fc240a926f49615f34c133df956f038a856f3/framework/web/Request.php#L792-L819).

Comment: It's not working, but this time I think it is some problem with the base tag, because I've tried to use the base tag other day, and it does not change the root of links.

I was trying to follow this tutorial, on how to build my own mvc, my code is exactly the same, but I can't understand why my code doesn't work as well. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_HFX63Q-dI&t=84s

Comment: @GustavoH.Ribeiro Make sure that your links does not have a leading slash.

Comment: Perfect, you're right, thanks!!! I'm gonna mark as answered, but I've got a problem with the public folder when it comes to accessing static content inside the public folder without having to explicitly specify the **public** name.